# Where can I find Ebony Mine in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm looking to make a  complete set of Daedric Armor and I need Ebony Ore to do so. Please help!!!!

PS I already know about Shor's Stone and have discovered it already but I would also like to know how to get to Gloombound :)

Answer (score 9):

[Ebony locations (UESPWiki)](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ebony) are listed here. That site is probably a better first port of call for basic Skyrim questions.

Answer (score 1):

Gloombound Mine E/SE of Windhelm is the best source. It's near the Orc Stronghold Narzulbur.

Edit: realized you already mentioned Gloombound. As I noted, it's slightly southeast of Windhelm, in the mountains. You'll probably see the Orc Stronghold first; it's attached to that.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is go southeast from windhelm and keep going that way until you find a cave logo on your top map that tells you where your current mission tells you to go. (You will know you found it when you reach a mine that is filled with orcs)